Attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'create_habit_window'
I am trying to make a habit tracker and create a window called create_habit_window with Customtkinter. but its keeps sayin that in create_habit
    self.create_habit_window = customtkinter.CTk()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create_habit_window'

self.create_new_habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text='Create New Habit', command=CreateHabit.create_habit(self.k), fg_color='green').pack(pady=20)

class CreateHabit:

def create_habit(self):
        self.create_habit_window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.create_habit_window.geometry('500x500')
        self.new_habit_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.create_habit_window, placeholder_text='Enter Habit Name')
        self.new_habit_entry.pack(pady=30)
        self.options = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly']
        self.new_habit_Combo = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.create_habit_window, values=self.options, )
        self.new_habit_Combo.pack(pady=20)
        self.new_habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.create_habit_window, text='Create New Habit', command= CreateHabit.commit_habit)
        self.new_habit_button.pack(pady=30)
        self.create_habit_window.mainloop()

The first line of code is where i call the method. I call it in a different class called HabitTracker.

First: the function should be inside the class (I assume it's just a mistake when posting the question, but please fix it). Second: You should post the code where you instantiate the class and call the method create_habit. self  should definitely not be a string, so there must be additional code that you haven't posted that is wrong. You should also post the complete traceback of the error you are getting properly formatted. Also the error in the title doesn't match the error in the explanation. Please edit your question and fix all this points.

In general, when in doubt, extract a [mcve] from your code. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

What is self.k in the first line of posted code?


I am trying to make a habit tracker and create a window called
create_habit_window with Customtkinter. but its keeps sayin that in
create_habit
self.create_habit_window = customtkinter.CTk()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create_habit_window'


The problem can be fixed.
Structure of a simple program with classes (recommended):
Snippet:
import customtkinter

class CreateHabit(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x500")
        self.title("CTk example")
        self.create_habit()

    def create_habit(self):
            
            self.new_habit_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text='Enter Habit Name')
            self.new_habit_entry.pack(pady=30)
            self.options = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly']
            self.new_habit_Combo = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self, values=self.options, )
            self.new_habit_Combo.pack(pady=20)
            self.new_habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text='Create New Habit',  )
            self.new_habit_button.pack(pady=30)
            #self.create_habit_window.mainloop()


app = CreateHabit()
app.mainloop()

Screenshot:

